# Header In the chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using `\listoftables` before starting a chapter.
But in the header of the chapter List of tables appear.

How can that be removed?

Comment: This does not happen with the standard setup, because there's no header at all in the chapter starting page. You probably have some non standard settings and an answer like Christian's is just a shot in the dark. Please add a minimal example showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\markboth{}{}\cleardoublepage` after `\listoftables`

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\markboth{}{}
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Foo}

\begin{table}
\caption{This is my table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```